# Regular expression of string without number and char in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have no idea how to make the pattern of the regular expression of a line of string containing ONLY alphabet.

```
var pattern = //the pattern is here;
var name = "My Name";
if(!pattern.test(name))
{
   return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Please, Help me.

Comment: Use `return /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test('My Name');` which will return `false` because it contains space.

Comment: I think /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/. It's return true if name value has space.

Comment: Yes indeed did not read properly the asked question, the pattern of ndn and Tushar are correct

Answer (score 1):

If you search a little bit about the basics of regex, you will find that you can use a pattern to match ranges, for instance:

```
[A-Z] ----> will match letter from A to Z in upper case where
[a-z] ----> will match letter from A to Z in lower case.
[A-Za-z] -> will match all letters from A-Z case insensitive
```

Then, if you are lazy, you can use an insensitive flag like

```
(?i)[a-z]
```

So, for your what you stated about ONLY alphabet, you can use:

```
(?i)^[a-z]+$    But this won't match: `My Name` because you have a space.
(?i)^[a-z ]+$   This will match: `My Name`
```

You can read more on http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Btw, if you show some effort in your question and post your attempt you can avoid community to downvote